# TYPO3 RTE Stripping out images

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I am having an issue with a TYPO3 site which seems to be stripping out images whenever I view it in the backend.

I have a page which has images on it (on the frontend), but when I go to edit it in the backend, I don't see the images. I then try to save it and the images are removed and not showing on the front end. The images are replaced with ' ' and I can't figure out why.

The config in my tsconfig.ts file for RTE is:

```
RTE.default {
    # Default target for links
    #defaultLinkTarget = _top


    # Buttons to show
  showButtons := removeFromList(about)
  #showButtons := addToList(fonticon)

    RTEHeightOverride = 500
    RTEWidthOverride = 700
    rteResize = 1

    enableWordClean = 1
    removeTrailingBR = 1
    removeComments = 1
    removeTagsAndContents = style,script
    showStatusBar = 1
    # Specifies that Mozilla/Firefox should not provide handles for resizing objects such as tables (and images)
    disableObjectResizing = 1

    buttons {
        left.useClass = text-left
        center.useClass = text-center
        right.useClass = text-right
        justifyfull.useClass = text-justify

        blockstyle.tags {
            #table.allowedClasses >
            table.allowedClasses = table, table-striped, table-bordered, table-hover, table-condensed
            div.allowedClasses = table-responsive
            p.allowedClasses = lead, text-left, text-center, text-right, small
            blockquote.allowedClasses = pull-left, pull-right

            h1.allowedClasses = text-left, text-center, text-right
            h2.allowedClasses = text-left, text-center, text-right
            h3.allowedClasses = text-left, text-center, text-right
            h4.allowedClasses = text-left, text-center, text-right

            tr.allowedClasses = success, danger, warning, active
            td.allowedClasses = text-left, text-center, text-right, success, danger, warning, active
        }
        formatblock {
            removeItems = article,aside,footer,header,h6,nav,section
            orderItems = h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, quotation, div
        }
        textstyle {
            tags.span.allowedClasses >
            #tags.span.allowedClasses = text-warning, text-danger, text-info, text-success
            tags.REInlineTags >
            REInlineTags >
        }

        link {
            # enable field for link rel-attribute
            relAttribute.enabled = 1
            properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(lightbox,btn btn-default,btn btn-primary,btn btn-info,btn btn-inverse,btn btn-primary btn-lg,btn btn-info btn-lg)
        }

        table {
            disableEnterParagraphs = 1
            # for firefox only: show special inline row/col manipulation "icons" (not useful)
            #enableHandles = 1
        }
    }


    proc {
        overruleMode = ts_css
        dontConvBRtoParagraph = 1
        remapParagraphTag = p
        entryHTMLparser_db.tags.img >



 #allowTags := addToList(button)
    denyTags >
    #keepPDIVattribs = xml:lang,class,style,align,id
    keepPDIVattribs = xml:lang,class,id

    #allowedClasses  < RTE.default.classesCharacter
    allowedClasses (
        external-link, internal-link, download, mail,
        text-left, text-center, text-right, text-justify,
        text-info, text-success, text-warning, text-danger
        lead, badge,
        table, success, warning, danger, active,
        lightbox, indent,
        btn, btn-default, btn-primary, btn-info, btn-success, btn-warning, btn-danger, btn-inverse, btn-link, btn-lg, btn-sm, btn-xs
    )

    allowTagsOutside = img,hr,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,br,ul,ol,li,pre,address,span,blockquote
    allowTagsInTypolists = br,font,b,i,u,a,img,span

    # Remapping b and i to strong and em (in FE)
    exitHTMLparser_db = 1
    exitHTMLparser_db {
        allowTags < RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags
        tags.b.remap = strong
        tags.i.remap = em

        # fix/cleanup RTE stuff <p style="line-height: 1.428...">
        rmTagIfNoAttrib = div, span
        tags.p.fixAttrib.style.unset = 1
        tags.span.fixAttrib.style.unset = 1
        tags.div.fixAttrib.style.unset = 1
    }

    exitHTMLparser_rte = 1
    exitHTMLparser_rte  {
      allowTags < RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags
      keepNonMatchedTags = 1
    }


}
```

}

I am using typo3 8.7.2 and the RTE plugin is rtehtmlarea

Comment: Update to TYPO3 8.7.20 first. May problem is solved then.

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled images in the extension config?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but it didn't work - I seem to have sorted it as it was conflicting with CKEditor which did no actually have a config

Comment: I was surprised that you were still using rtehtmlarea, because the CKeditor as default was introduced with 8

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was using CKEditor, htmlarea was installed and configured but CKEditor was instead being loaded and using it's default template which removes images from RTE fields